# Backup google drive workspace to local server

Tags: automation, backup, local, google-workspace, rclone

Automatically backup google drive to local server

Hello,

We use Google Workspace.

I would like to find a way to automatically back up our files to Google on a local server via a cron job.

I know doing a local backup to google drive is possible via rclone.

Would it be possible to use rclone in the direction Google drive -> local server?

Obviously Google offers a way to retrieve the data via https://admin.google.com/ac/customertakeout but that does not correspond to what I want to do. Ideally, I would like to have automatic local backups in case of hacks etc.

Otherwise, maybe only with a python script and the google API, but I can't find anything in the google documentation that explains this.